# I want to exchange UK Pound for Indian Rupee

Tags: foreign-exchange, money-transfer, inr-indian-rupee, gbp-british-pound

I have a friend in London, recently he has sent a parcel for me including some pound (England Currency ) in that parcel, now how can I exchange it into Indian Rupee ??

Comment: Where are you located - are you in India? What form is the money in - actual cash banknotes, or a cheque, or travellers' cheques, or...? What kind of amount are we talking - a few pounds, several thousand pounds...? Without this information it's hard to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are located in India and you have few pounds of currency notes, you can walk into any Bank-Branch that deals with Foreign Currency and get this exchanged into Indian Rupees.

Alternatively there are quite a few Fx dealers in almost all large cities, a Western Union can also help you get this exchanged.